# Rspec: connecting to multiple readonly databases not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sharding

I am on Rails 7.0.3 & ruby 2.7.4p191 and have the following model definition

```
class ExternalRecord < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  #establish_connection :main_red
  connects_to database: {
    main_red: :main_red,
    main_green: :main_green,
    main_blue: :main_blue
  }
end
```

I want to switch to reading from different databases based on few conditions, this seems to be working very well on development environment

i am using below code to switch to different databases

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: @main_db_name.to_sym) do
        result = Api::V2::Gom::T1::Platform.ransack(params[:q]).result.page(params[:page]).per(get_rows_limit)
      end
```

but when when i try to run rspec tests, i get an error

hers is the relevant code in the test

```
RSpec.shared_examples "NON EMPTY(US Horizontals)" do |end_point, token|
  it "/#{end_point}" do
    get("/api/v2/#{end_point}", params: {
      authentication_token: @token,
    })
    data = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(response.status).to eql(200)
    expect(data).to be_an_instance_of(Array)
    expect(data.count).to be > 0
  end
end
```

in the processing of the request is where i switch to different database based on the certain conditions,but this is generating the following error.

```
ArgumentError (The `pool_config` for the :reading_main_red role and :default shard was `nil`. Please check your configuration. If you want your writing role to be something other than `:writing` set `config.active_record.writing_role` in your application configuration. The same setting should be applied for the `reading_role` if applicable.):
database.yml as pool setting.
```

it would be great if someone can point me in the right directions, could it be something related my rails configuration or may be something in rspec that i a missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the first few lines of the stacktrace for the ArgumentError, and also your `database.yml` for your dev and test environments. Then also can you comment on whether you have any automatic switching middleware setup in your `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/test.rb`? (you're looking for anything starting with  `config.active_record.database_`)